# How to disable animation in aws devicefarm for android espresso test

Tags: android, animation, amazon-web-services, android-espresso, aws-device-farm

I am running some android tests on AWS DeviceFarm and want to disable the animation. I came across this [discussion](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx20RGXMTYT2ZGZ/Getting-started-with-Android-testing-on-AWS-Device-Farm-using-Espresso-Part-3-Up) and one guy suggested to pass `--no-window-animation` parameter. I am not able to figure out where to pass this parameter and how?

Comment from the forum:

> Hi Mark, we currently pass the argument "–no-window-animation" for
>   instrumentation-based tests, including Espresso. If you believe
>   animations are not disabled for your tests or you're referring to a
>   different setting please let me know so we can investigate. Thanks!
>   Posted by  Trent@AWS  on  October 28, 2015 3:02:16 PM PDT

Commands I have already gone through:

- aws devicefarm schedule-run
- aws devicefarm get-upload
- aws devicefarm create-upload

Could anyone help me to disable animation? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am work for the AWS Device farm team.

I assume from your description that you are trying to run Espresso/Instrumentation tests on Android.

When we say that we pass the argument it means that you do not have to explicitly pass the argument from any commands or tests. When the instrumentation runner is executed those arguments are already passed in. Since you do not start the runner on device farm it is started by the service for you with that argument.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful, and is there way to look into more detailed error messages?

Comment: The log display under each test or the Files tab should give you all of the logs from your run in addition to the error message that gets bubbled up on the console. Is that what you were looking for?